# wso2 identity server getting forbidden while accessing xacml sample mention in document

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

In wso2 identity server 5.11(https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/writing-a-custom-policy-info-point/) document while accessing custom PIP attribute finder sample files it is showing forbidden error for svn directory.

Below are the links which are forbidden but mentioned as sample in wso2 doc:
https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/asela/xacml/pip/jdbc/src/main/org/xacmlinfo/xacml/pip/jdbc/KMarketJDBCAttributeFinder.java

https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/asela/xacml/pip/jdbc/resources/dbScript/testUserStore.sql

https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/asela/xacml/pip/jdbc/

[image]